# ghc can't find my cabal installed packages

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've installed ghc 6.12.3, and then the Haskell Platform. I'm trying to compile a test program:

```
$ ghc test.hs
test.hs:3:0:
    Failed to load interface for `Bindings':
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

so, naturally, I do

```
cabal install Bindings
```

Which works fine, and places the package in ~/.cabal/lib/bindings-0.1.2 The problem is, that when I go to compile again with ghc, it still doesn't find the package I've installed with cabal.
compiling in verbose mode gives:

```
ghc -v test.hs
Using binary package database: /home/ludflu/ghc/lib/ghc-6.12.3/package.conf.d/package.cache
Using binary package database: /home/ludflu/.ghc/x86_64-linux 6.12.3/package.conf.d/package.cache
```

As suggested by another stackoverflow user, I tried:

```
ghc-pkg describe rts > rts.pkg
vi rts.pkg                      # add the /home/ludflu/.cabal/lib to `library-dirs` field
ghc-pkg update rts.pkg
```

But to no avail.  How to I add the .cabal to the list of package directories to search? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check which packages are installed with `ghc-pkg list`. It may be that you need to either specify the packages to `ghc` with `-package <pkgname>` or I believe adding `--make` to will trigger a chasing down of dependencies, including packages.

**Edit:** the bindings package is obsolete indeed, see [the hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-0.1.2). This isn't a package management problem, the only module available is `Bindings.Deprecated`, which you are perfectly able to load, even though it is an empty module. I believe the relevant parts have been broken out into `bindings-<module>`, so if you want the bindings functionality you should look to those packages.

Comment: ghc-list produces a list of packages that does include Bindings. It looks like the package is deprecated - so its not being found. Adding the -package argument didn't help. I tried some of the other examples that didn't use Bindings, and they worked fine, so I'm going to obsess on some other problems! :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-install

One thing to be especially aware of, is that the packages are installed locally by default by cabal, whereas the commands

```
runhaskell Setup configure
runhaskell Setup build
runhaskell Setup install
```

install globally by default. If you install a package globally, the local packages are ignored. The default for cabal-install can be modified by editing the configuration file.

I was getting the same error with the `runhaskell` command. I used the cabal in the directory that had the .cabal file and was able to resolve the error.