# GHCI unable to recognize packages installed with Cabal on windows 10

Tags: windows, haskell, package, cabal

I am a beginner with Haskell and for an assignment I needed to install System.Random. So I installed the package using Cabal through command line (originally with `cabal install random` and then with `cabal install --lib random`), however, when I run GHCI it doesn't recognize that the package is installed. When I run it I get this error:

```
Could not find module `System.Random'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import System.Random
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I tried a few things to fix this, however, none of them seem to work. I tried to copy the files from the cabal directory where the package is saved and place them in the same folder as my project but I received this error.

```
     File name does not match module name:
    Saw: `Main'
    Expected: `Random'
  |
1 | #if __GLASGOW_HASKELL__ >= 701
  | ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I then attempted to run ghc with "ghc -iC:\DirectoryToPackage AssignmentThatCallsPackage.hs" and this gave the same error as above. I also attempted this solution given here [ghc can't find my cabal installed packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641684/ghc-cant-find-my-cabal-installed-packages) the second answer to make the package global but when I tried to run the line "runhaskell Setup install" it gave me an access denied error. I feel I have tried other solutions, but I can't remember what else I tried at the moment. I have been stuck on this for a while now so any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assuming you are using a recent version of Cabal (3.0 or above), `cabal install --lib random` (note the `--lib` option) should be enough to make the package available in the default GHCi environment. [This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61512017/2751851) is probably relevant.

Comment: I tried that as well before I attempted the stuff above. Ill add that to the original post.

Comment: @cksssssss If you go into an empty folder, type `cabal install --lib --package-env . random` and then start `ghci` in that same folder, does it work? Also, `cabal install` doesn't install the binaries in GHC's package database, but in one under control of cabal itself.

Comment: @danidiaz When I try to use that in the command line it comes back with this : https://gyazo.com/41376d71c6152b8bfe0badec8fd2207c . If you don't want to click the link essentially it is saying that cabal option "--lib" is ambiguous and could be a list of other library options.  How can i install the binaries in the GHC package database as well then?

Comment: @cksssssss What version of `cabal` are you using? (`cabal --version`). If the version is < 3.0 perhaps you could try downloading the cabal-install windows executable from here https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html decompress it with a program like 7-Zip, and then put the executable in your Windows PATH, for example using the "Edit environment variables for your account" menu. Then try again `cabal install --lib --package-env . random` in a local folder.