# cabal doesn't seem to register installed packages

Tags: haskell, installation, package, cabal

I just upgraded GHC from version 8.10.2 to 8.10.3 on Windows 10 using Chocolatey, and cabal doesn't seem to work properly. I tried to install ieee754 for use with Agda, the installation went through without problem. The compiled files are in `%AppData%\cabal\store`, but neither `cabal list --installed` nor `ghc-pkg list` outputs it as an installed package, and `import Numeric.IEEE` in ghci results in an error. However, cabal outputs *Up to date* upon rerunning `cabal install ieee754`, so apparently cabal knows the package is installed, but somehow did not register it as installed. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250834/haskell-problem-importing-system-random-windows#comment115357125_65250834, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62335595/ghci-unable-to-recognize-packages-installed-with-cabal-on-windows-10, and a lot of similar questions. The advice that I generally give is to _never use `cabal install --lib` at all_. Instead, create a small package of your own and add random to its dependencies. Specifically for an actual project like Agda you shouldn't need to do this at all, because it already lists the dependencies itself.

Comment: I second @leftaroundabout 's suggestion. It is generally a good idea to have a Cabal project for your code. Even if it's just for trying out stuff, you can `cabal init` a throwaway project and add whatever you want to play with to its `build-depends`. (Feel free to ping me if the advice here or in the linked questions doesn't suffice.)